# Datepicker date not picked by textbox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a couple of modals with textboxes inside with whom i bound the jquery ui datapicker. But, on date selection the date is not updated to the textbox. Here is my code:

```
<form id="frm_edit" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('asset/edit') . '/' . $row['as_id']; ?>">
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <div id="edit_error" style="color: #990000;"></div>
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Return Date</label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                                            <input type="text" id="rt_date" name="rt_date" class="form-control dt" placeholder="Enter Date"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Save changes</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
$(".dt").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true});
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: I solved it Bro. But, thanks a lot.